# (physics of an idealized string) Show that this expanding cylinder will unravel this loop

Tags: algebraic-topology, physics, mathematical-physics, geometric-topology, knot-theory

Below is a really hard problem which seems to be on the intersection of math and physics, so I'm posting this to both math and physics stack exchange. I thought of it when reading a knot theory book.

Below in the picture, you see the projection of an unknot (a basic looped string in space).
[image]

The red dot marks an infinite line going into your screen perpendicularly. Assume that we know the line weaves through the "inside" of the loop rather than the outside.

Now imagine the dot starts expanding uniformly as a cylinder outwards. Prove/disprove that eventually, the unknot shown above will unravel into a circular band that hugs/wraps around the cylinder. Will this happen in any generalized context?

Assume the cylinder has infinite mass and no friction. Assume the unknot is comprised of an idealized string (e.g. no friction, no mass, no volume, infinite ability to twist, no stretching, infinite strength etc.) Assume that there is no other forces that I didn't mention.

Note that I don't even know if this is true, but it seems highly intuitive that when you pull hard enough, any frictionless loop will unravel. (provided that it's not doubly looped around the cylinder)

Comment: "Idealized string" is actually a very tricky.  If you don't define this correctly, what can happen is that the "knotted" part gets smaller and smaller, shrinking to a point and disappearing.  Even if we were fine with this being very non-physical, this is bad in theory too because it makes all knots unknotted.  Even physical simulations where you put a uniform electric charge on a knot to try to unknot it can have this type of singularity.

Comment: @KyleMiller interesting, is there an accepted "canon" for such strings? From what you say it sounds like attempts to study knots via physical simulations

Comment: Unknot is a loop that satisfying some conditions? Isn't this about winding number?

Comment: You should link to [your other closely-related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4300638/how-to-tell-if-a-straight-line-will-pass-through-a-closed-loop-in-3-space). This question belongs here. It is a mathematical problem, not truly a physics problem.

Comment: Rather than some ungodly mess as above. You should first investigate the simplest cases possible. In particular, the [Trefoil Knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot).

Comment: Some pointers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_energy  I don't know too much about it, but I think what applies to your cylinder idea is that you need to be very careful about singularities (like what it says about regularization for electric potential).  "Repulsive curves" by Yu-Schumacher-Crane seems very interesting (accessible from [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/index.html))